# Does the trace distance between marginals bound the distance between the overall states?

Tags: quantum-state, linear-algebra, trace-distance

If the quantum states of the subsystems of two systems are close (for example: in terms of trace distance), are the states of the larger systems also close, i.e., if
$$ ||\rho_A - \rho_{A^\prime}||\leq \epsilon$$ and $$ ||\rho_B - \rho_{B^\prime}||\leq \epsilon,$$
can we claim that  $$ ||\rho_{AB} - \rho_{A^\prime B^\prime}||\leq \delta(\epsilon)$$?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Just take two Bell states. They have identical reduced density matrices yet are orthogonal, that is, as distant from each other as it gets.